# Fetching data using eact native

Tags: django, react-native

I am trying to fetch my user infomations from django database. But I only get the following message

```
 {"_bodyBlob": {"_data": {"__collector": [Object], "blobId": "ee5e4317-5bb7-4b5f-8e19-7a787cdee766", "offset": 0, "size": 94}}, "_bodyInit": {"_data": {"__collector": [Object], "blobId": "ee5e4317-5bb7-4b5f-8e19-7a787cdee766", "offset": 0, "size": 94}}, "bodyUsed": false, "headers": {"map": {"allow": "GET, POST, HEAD, OPTIONS", "content-length": "94", "content-type": "application/json", "date": "Sat, 19 Mar 2022 22:02:40 GMT", "referrer-policy": "same-origin", "server": "WSGIServer/0.2 CPython/3.6.8", "vary": "Accept, Origin, Cookie", "x-content-type-options": "nosniff", "x-frame-options": "DENY"}}, "ok": true, "status": 200, "statusText": "", "type": "default"
```

I can use it to determine if the status is OK to long in, but I would like to be able to gather the user information and send them to the next page.

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the issue by using async function.

```
 fetch('http://XXXXXX/api/userprofile',{
             method  : 'GET',
            header : {
            Accept  : 'application/json',
            'Content-Type' : 'application/json'
            } 
            }).then(async res =>{ 
                const response =await res.json() 
                console.log(response)
                })
```